# Muse centering anyobject within textbox

Tags: muse

Hi i need to place 3rd party widgets in to a text box which is 100% width centered.. anything else no matter what is working very fine inside a text box but i cannot place any widgets in there did anyone tried this out. Thanks in advance..
to mention the main reason i had to place things inside a textbox as it is keeping thing always centered is i can not keep my menu buttons in mobile same size as the land scape mode is no matter which OS always zooming in.. safter i have fixed that issue so no more zoom in by landscape turns then the portrait elements where left bounded regarding the size of the portrait scene compared to landscape so the mobile menu layout in Muse is even centered it is only device and not browser centered..

Answer (score 0):

To place any Widget/Image or anything else other than text in a TextBox, you first need to drag the Widget into the canvas, then cut/copy it. Then select the TextBox as if you were about to type in it, and then paste your item in it, just like if it was text.